# How to find a particular string

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2017

Im using Visual Studio 2017 and in a long long text file Im searching for a particular function but unable to find

here's what the regex Im using

```
c\.CreateMap\<(\w)+\,\s+Address\>
```

and I want to in these

```
c.CreateMap<ClientAddress, Address>()

c.CreateMap<Responses.SiteAddress, Data.Address>()
```

and so on.

As soon as I add "Address" in the regex it stops matching any.
what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I just did :D ..

Comment: Your first line matches just fine. Your second line does not match because the first item there `Responses.SiteAddress` does not match `\w+` - it doesn't contain just word characters

Comment: change (\w)+ to (\w)+\.?(\w)+,

Comment: `c\.CreateMap[^)]+\)`

Comment: @Pedro Lobito that doesn't match the things I want

Comment: I tried.... nope.. even the first one doesn't match

Comment: Which **things** are you referring to? Make sure you post questions where the input and desired output are clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can try this**

```
c\.CreateMap\<\w+\.?\w+?\,\s*\w*?\.?Address\>
```

> Explanation

- `c\.CreateMap\<` - Matches `c\.CreateMap\<`.
- `\w+` - Matches any word character one or more time.
- `\.?` - Matches '.' zero or one time.
- `\,` - Matches ','.
- `\s*` - Matches space zero or more time.
- `\w` - Matches word character zero or more time.
- `\.?` - Matches '.' zero or one time.
- `Address\>` - Matches `Address\>`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/TKjVdp/4)

**P.S**- In case you also want to match something like this.

```
c.CreateMap<Responses.SiteAddress.abc, Data.Address.xyz>()
```

**You can use this.**

```
c\.CreateMap\<(\w+\.?\w+?)*\,\s*(?:\w*?\.?)*Address(\.\w*)?\>
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/TKjVdp/5)

Comment: @SimpleFellow Always happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is general regex I can suggest:

```
c\.CreateMap\<[\w.]+,\s+(?:[\w.]+\.)?Address\>\s*\(\s*\)
```

This will match any term with dots or word characters in the first position in the diamond.  In the second, position, it will match `Address`, or some parent class names, followed by a dot separator, followed by `Address`.

### Demo

Note that I also include the empty function call parentheses in the regex.  As well, I allow for flexibility in the whitespace may appear after the diamond, or between the parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

In your second example, you have extra dot which is not handled. Your regex needs little modification. Also, you don't need to escape `<` or `>` or `,` Use this,

```
c\.CreateMap<([\w.])+,\s+[\w.]*Address>
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/szaNI0/1)**

Answer (score 0):

To match any of the functions on your question, you can use:

```
c\.CreateMap[^)]+\)
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/r08ATw/1)

Regex Explanation:
[image]

Comment: that code is related to AutoMapper and I want to find all mappings whose destination is "Address" not anything else in a long file or rather files. your regex finds all mappings not just the one targeting Address.